# Talend data Integration : How to maintain input columns in all the components?

Tags: talend

My Input sheet has 3 fields
I1,I2 and I3

I have to insert these fields in two tables.

Table1 should have I1 and I2 from input field and It has ID as PK column. 
Table2 should have I3. Foreign key relation Table1 ID.

Using talend, I have inserted first two columns data in table1 (I3 is omitted in this table output component)  and I have auto incremented ID. Now I want to insert ID and I3 into Table out.

But In the second table output I could not see I3 column in stream since we have omitted I3 in the first step.

Can you anyone help how to get I3 column for second table output component?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this in following way...

Over all job view:
[image: Over all job view]

tMap Settings:
[image: tMap Settings]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do so with a simple tMap with 2 outputs :

```
tDBInput --- tMap ---tDBOutput1
                  ---tDBOutput2
```

In tMap, you just have to select the fields to put in the right output.
You can use Talend sequence Numeric.sequence("s1",1,1) in the 'Var' section of the tMap (central panel), and put it in the 2 outputs as an ID.

Comment: If I use Numeric.sequence("s1",1,1), that could create issue while inserting data(Duplicate Entry since ID is auto incremented value). This solution will work temporarily. But it may not good solution for longer term purposes.

Comment: If you plan to run it multiple times (not a one-shot execution), you could read your target-table as a lookup on the tMap, and get the max(ID). Then you start Numeric.sequence from this maxID instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be with a two-step process. You can create two separate "processing lines" or subjobs within one job.

**Step 1 - l1, l2**

First subjob would be, as @Corentin said,

```
tExcelInput1 -- tMap1 -- tDBOutput1 (l1, l2)
```

**Step 2 - l3**

Second subjob, which can be connected with *tDBInput1 onSubjobOk* connector, would look like this

```
tExcelInput2 -- tMap2 -- tDBOutput2 (l3)
              |--- tDBInput3, lookup ID (with l1)
```

Now the first subjob adds all values to table 1. When everything worked out fine, all values for l3 are processed with an ID lookup on l1. This would work with a auto-increment field in the database. The lookup would simply look like `SELECT ID FROM table1` and in the *tMap*, just use l3 for the lookup.

**Overview**

If it is easier for you to see the job, please check the following image.

[image]

The lookup would look like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi there, Really thank you very much for this post. I did this job in the same way but how can we make sure that the ID and I3 would be come from same row. Also, this kind of job will be used one time. If it is a scheduled job, how can we take ID for new inserted rows (Lets assume we already have rows in table 1)? Suppose if insertion order changed while inserting rows in table 1, what will happen? Kindly suggest these kind of scenarios...

Comment: You are right. The lookup should happen against `row3.l1` and `row3.l2`,  *if those rows are actually unique*. If new data is *also* unique, the job will run fine every time you call it. Since we are talking only about table schemas, I just took a guess.